# Load jquery cookie data to a div

Tags: jquery, cookies, session-cookies

Hi I have created a cookie using "jquery.cookie.js" and I use below script to create the cookie onClick

```
onClick="$.cookie('bincookie','title_attribute'),{ expires: 7, path: '/' }"
```

I can see my cookie is successfully created in browser console and now my issue is how to load the title attribute saved as cookie in to a another  div or H1 tag on another page.

bincookie is my cookie name. I'll appreciate if someone can help me on this.
In title attribute I'm loading a post title in wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to get the cookie data using below

```
<pre>
        $.cookie('bincookie');
        document.getElementById("cookie_title").innerHTML = $.cookie("bincookie"); 
</pre>
```

Thanks for taking the time to answer my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using old jquery cookie from: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

In that case do like:

```
//in document ready
$('#myH1Id').text($.cookie('bincookie'));
```